Add FontAutoScalingEnabled for Items in Telerik .Net Maui Controls
I currently have a Telerik ComboBox in .Net Maui. I mainly want to use the default stylings (except for some colors, as you can see in the code), but I want to disable FontAutoScalingEnabled on every text/label item.
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     Placeholder="{x:Static resx:Labels.ItemCategory}"
                     SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <telerik:RadComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource White}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Black}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem}" Value="True" TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource White}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadComboBox.Style>
</telerik:RadComboBox>

How can I set FontAutoScalingEnabled for all labels in the ComboBox (selectable Items and selectedItem)?
Thanks in advance!
